# Azure Batch - Create Nodes from VM Image

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have some Selenium test code that I need to run in parallel. In order for Selenium to run effectively, certain configurations have to be done on the machine (I.E. zone settings, Chrome and Firefox installs, etc.) and these settings are hard (if not impossible) to apply via an automated approach. I've manually created a VM, done all the setup and created an image following the directions in [Microsoft's documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/).

Now I need to setup my code so that I can specify a VM image to use when creating the nodes. I've searched as much as I can and not found any documentation that explains how I can go about doing this. [The example in the DotNetTutorial sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/ArticleProjects/DotNetTutorial) doesn't seem to have any way to specify an image.

There is a [feedback item here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/269742-batch/suggestions/6621822-support-of-customized-vm-image-iaas-on-batch-ser) on this same topic and shows the request as started on Jun 1st 2015. I'm hoping this means that it's done now and that it just hasn't been documented well.

---

**Q: How I can specify a custom VM image as the source for my Azure Batch nodes?**

---

Comment: The feedback items rarely have much basis in reality unfortunately, There are a lot of items that get put to 'Started' that stay like that for a considerable time. Even staying that way when it is implemented. I have a suspicion that anything that is on the roadmap is put as started and left like that until it gets done.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer on 2017-12-05:**

Custom images are now supported through normal Batch accounts (i.e., Batch service pool allocation mode accounts). You will need to specify a valid ARM Image Id and use Azure Active Directory authentication to create custom images (shared key auth does not support custom images).

**Updated Answer on 2017-03-17:**

Custom images are now supported through "User Subscription" Batch accounts. You can create these types of accounts in Azure Portal  or through the newest management SDKs for supported languages.

**Previous Answer:**

Currently, custom VM images are not supported. As you noted, this is a feature that is being worked on. In addition to uservoice, you can periodically [check for product updates at this site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?product=batch).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/AutoRest/src/Batch/Client/changelog.md

•   Added support for deploying nodes using custom VHDs, via the OSDisk property of VirtualMachineConfiguration. Note that the Batch account being used must have been created with PoolAllocationMode = UserSubscription to allow this.